# Liquid Diet - Good or Bad?

Tags: diet

Is liquid dieting good for your health, if supplemented with adequate and appropriate vitamin supplements?

Will it's effect on running prove to be worse from less energy, or better from less load?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liquid diets in general don't work for the long term.  Even if all the Calories, macro and micro nutrients are perfectly balanced the fundamental problem is one of satiety.  If you don't feel satisfied with what you've consumed, the urge is very strong to cheat.

Our bodies are designed to masticate our food, and without this stimulous we instinctively feel something is missing.  Additionally, most liquids are highly processed.  While this means you can have higher absorption rates, it also means that it just doesn't stick with you.  Whey protein isolates, the gold standard for "quick absorbing protein" will leave you hungry within half an hour.  You'll also notice that the packaging on protein powder says to not use the powder as your exclusive source of nutrition.

That said, a liquid diet can be an effective short term solution to shed some pounds.  By short term we are talking no more than 90 days, and preferably 1-2 months.  It has the advantage of simplifying your shopping requirements and food preparation.  It has the disadvantage of cost, and a nagging feeling of hunger.  You may adjust well enough after a couple weeks, but it still leaves you desiring something to chew.

Comment: Thanks Berin, I would up-vote your answer, but I don't have enough points. Great answer.